# Accept decimal value upto 99.99

Tags: javascript, regex, floating-point, decimal

There is a demo created [DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oK7eW9/9) and it is working as i expect but i am not able to add any value more after `24.99` but i need value which can be upto `99.99`

Tried modifying the demo `regex` but it is not working as expected.

this is the `Regex`

```
^(0+)?(24(\.00?)?|(\.00?)?|\.[0-9]+|0?[0-9](\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(0+)?[0-2][0-3](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)$
```

can some one help me on this?

Comment: change the 24 near the start to 99?

Comment: Based on your comment, why not `function isValidInput(value) { var val = parseFloat(value); return !isNaN(val) && val >= 0 && val <= 99.99; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/scek2xyg/ - faster and safer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match `0.00` - `99.99` to any number of decimal places, plus edge cases like `.43` and `43.`:

```
^0*((((9[0-8]?)|([0-8][0-9]?))?(\.[0-9]*)?)|(99(\.(([0-8][0-9]*)|(9(90*|([0-8][0-9]*))))?)?))$
```

[See Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uF1tI8/5)

Note that it will also match an empty string, so you should check for that first.

Although based on your comment to vks's answer, it is quicker and safer to just convert the value to a float and then check if it is range:

```
function isValidInput(value) {
    var val = parseFloat(value);
    return !isNaN(val) && val >= 0 && val <= 99.99;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scek2xyg/1/)

Answer (score 2):

```
^(0+)?(99(\.99?)?|(\.99?)?|\.[0-9]+|0?[0-9](\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(0+)?[0-9][0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oK7eW9/11

Comment: function isValidInput(value) 
  {
    
      var re = /^(0+)?(99(\.99?)?|(\.99?)?|\.[0-9]+|0?[0-9](\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(0+)?[0-9][0-9](\.[0-9][0-9]?)?)$/;
      return re.test(value);
     
  }This is how i used but it accepts everything.

Comment: yes you are right only but i am not pointing out any mistakes here and please correct the mistake i made that is the reason why i gave the method i used. thanks and pls dont mind.